# how to change a key value in mongodb when i push data with moloquent

Tags: mongodb, laravel, moloquent

```
$cart = Cart::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->push('cart', [ 
    "uuid" => uniqid(), 
    "product_id" => $request->product_id, 
    "product_type_id" => $request->product_type_id, 
    "address_id" => $request->address_id, 
    "voucher_id" => $request->voucher_id, 
    "coureer_id" => $request->coureer_id, 
    "note" => $request->note, 
    "qty" => $request->qty, 
    "type" => $request->type, 
    "expired_at" => $this->addWeekFromCurrentTime(4), 
    "created_at" => $this->getCurrentTime() 
]);
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpaKq.png)

how to change a key value in mongodb when i push data with moloquent

when i push, mongodb always generate a incremental key, how can i change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override _id becouse MongoDB always generate default ID for your bson or if you want disable it you could create colletions without default index

```
db.createCollection("coll", { autoIndexId: false })
```

this could be done in mongo console

Comment: Can i implement that in laravel?

Comment: Try to "_id" => your id  or if you want disable it you must find something i documentation of moloquent

Comment: if i have many document? thats not solve my problem, but still thangks dude